# Difference of two number divisible by 7

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

At least how many numbers are needed to be taken to be sure that there are at least 11 numbers among these numbers where the difference between any two is divisible by 7?

Comment: Hint: use PHP as in the linked dupes.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Pigeonhole principle. The differences between the $11$ numbers are all divisible by $7$ if and only if the $11$ numbers are all in the same residue class modulo $7$.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve it using the pigeonhole principle.

I found that if I take at least a = 7*n+1 numbers according to the pigeonhole principle there should be ceil{a/7} numbers whose difference between any two is surely divisible by 7.

So, found the solution to this question 71.